# Errors loading new flutter app on Mac with VsCode

Tags: flutter, macos, visual-studio-code

Im new to Flutter, sorry in advance....

When I try to create a new app in vscode via the command pallette, the app populates and looks fine for a second, in the bottom left I see text that says 'analyzing' then it shows 18 problems in the problems tab of vscode.

[This is the problems tab output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nD6yK.png)

I've tried to run flutter clean, flutter pub get and they don't help. My flutter doctor is all [green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eI2YG.png)

I have reinstalled the flutter and dart extensions on vscode, restarted vscode, started a new project, restarted my machine, and am out of runway on google. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else runs into this, the solution for me was to simply delete flutter and reinstall it. I didn't edit the path or do anything to my plugisn on vscode, just delete the flutter directory from wherever you downloaded it and reinstall it in the same place.

Viola.